# PrintWriter.println - works - but not print?

Tags: java, java-print, javaspaces

i have a really suspicious case here, envolving a simple method which is supposed to write into a .txt file.

```
public void extractCoNLL(int n, String outputFile) throws IOException {

    String msg;
    PrintWriter pr = new PrintWriter(outputFile);
    FileInputStream fConlliN = new FileInputStream(this.txt_CoNLL_in);
    BufferedReader readBufferData = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(fConlliN));

    try {
        while ((msg = readBufferData.readLine()) != null) {
            String aMsg[] = msg.split("\\s+");

            if (!msg.startsWith("#")) {
                //pr.println(msg);

                if (aMsg.length >= n) {
                    pr.print(aMsg[n] + "_");  // DOES NOT WORK
                    pr.println(aMsg[n] + "_");  // WORKS ?????
                    System.out.println(aMsg[4] + aMsg.length);
                } else {
                    pr.println();
                }
            }
        }
        this.txt_CoNLL = out_Extracted_txt_CoNLL;
    } catch (Exception e) {
        System.err.println("Error Exception: " + e.getMessage());
    }
}
```

Also, why is it not possible for me to add a simple " " -space but i have to be forced to use "_" to seperate the words.
Very grateful for your Help.
Thank you in advance!

Comment: In what way does that line not work? What is the error?

Comment: Im sorry, it was the other way around, just edited my post.

Comment: It doesnt save anything to the file, but pr.println does. it creates a line for each Word

Comment: `pr.flush()`. But, of course, you should be closing your streams.

Comment: should i write it like this
pr.flush(aMsg[n]);

Comment: Is it possible for you to put some sample of input file contents?

Comment: pr.print(aMsg[n] + " "); should work fine, as expected

Comment: Thank you it did, and thanks for the "close your streams" notice

Comment: use `printf` to give space in the string. e.g. `pr.printf("Hi %d", <int variable>)` will print `Hi <value of variable>`